# Want to add multiple records in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm try to develop an application using Spring MVC. For that I developed the wanted entities, daos, services. Those are completeled. But in the JSP I want to add multiple records to the Data Base using the controller. I made it as,

**addUser.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Category</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Add New Category</h2>

  <table>

    <form:form action="addCategory" method="post"
        modelAttribute="addCategoryObject">

        <tr>
            <td><label>Category :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Keyword 1 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="keySet[0].name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Keyword 2 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="keySet[1].name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Keyword 3:</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="keySet[2].name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Keyword 4 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="keySet[3].name" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Field Name 1 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="infoSet[0].name" /></td>

            <td><form:select path="infoSet[0].type">
                    <form:option value="1" label="Text Field" />
                    <form:option value="2" label="Court Location" />
                </form:select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Field Name 2 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="infoSet[1].name" /></td>

            <td><form:select path="infoSet[1].type">
                    <form:option value="1" label="Text Field" />
                    <form:option value="2" label="Court Location" />
                </form:select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Field Name 3 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="infoSet[2].name" /></td>

            <td><form:select path="infoSet[2].type">
                    <form:option value="1" label="Text Field" />
                    <form:option value="2" label="Court Location" />
                </form:select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Field Name 4 :</label></td>
            <td><form:input path="infoSet[3].name" /></td>

            <td><form:select path="infoSet[3].type">
                    <form:option value="1" label="Text Field" />
                    <form:option value="2" label="Court Location" />
                </form:select></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><label>Main Classification: </label></td>
            <td><select name="mainCategory">
                    <c:forEach var="mainCate" items="${mainCategoryList}">
                        <option>${mainCate}</option>
                    </c:forEach>
            </select></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add User" /></td>
        </tr>

      </form:form>

 </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the controller,

**UserController.java**

```
@Controller
public class AddCategoryController {

@Autowired
private CategoryService categoryService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/category", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView printWelcome(ModelMap model) {

    List<CategoryKey> categoryKeyList = new ArrayList<CategoryKey>();
    CategoryKey categoryKey = new CategoryKey();
    categoryKeyList.add(categoryKey);
    category.setKeySet(categoryKeyList);

    return new ModelAndView("addCategory", "addCategoryObject",new Category());
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/addCategory", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("addCategoryObject") Category category){

List<CategoryKey> categoryKey = category.getKeySet();
    CategoryKey categoryKeys = categoryKey.get(0);
    categoryKeys.setCategory(category);

    List<CategoryKey> categoryKeyList = new ArrayList<CategoryKey>();
    categoryKeyList.add(categoryKeys);
    category.setKeySet(categoryKeyList);

    categoryService.create(category);

    return "addCategory";

         }

     }
```

But it take only the first record. I think it's because "categoryKey.get(0)" this part. But I don't know a method to get all the records one by one or as a list from the jsp. I want to add those 4 records separatly to the DB. Please give me a solution. Thank You.

Comment: you are alomost there, please post the code for entities also, and complete jsp code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand your way but maybe it will work;

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/addCategory", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("addCategoryObject") Category category){

    List<CategoryKey> categoryKey = category.getKeySet();


        for(int i = 0; categoryKey.size() >i;i++){
       CategoryKey categoryKeys = categoryKey.get(i);

        categoryKeys.setCategory(category);

        List<CategoryKey> categoryKeyList = new ArrayList<CategoryKey>();
        categoryKeyList.add(categoryKeys);
        category.setKeySet(categoryKeyList);

        categoryService.create(category);
        }

        return "addCategory";



         }
```

Comment: Although my question is not clear you have provided a correct answer to me. Thank you hurricane